# Measure of Connectivity on a Chessboard

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-game-theory

I'm programming a boardgame...game. The basic idea of it is there are two players (call them $X$ and $Y$) that are trying to trying to build a wall connecting the North and South, and East and West sides, respectively, of a chessboard (however it can be larger or smaller than $8\times 8$ but the board is always square.) A typical board state would look something like this:

```
0 X 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 
Y 0 0 X Y 0  
0 Y X Y X 0 
0 0 Y 0 0 0 
0 0 X 0 0 0
```

Zero denotes an empty space. $Y$'s pretty close to winning. All $8$ directions between pieces count as connections. (I'm simplifying the rules a bit for the sake of clarity, I promise you the actual game is at least somewhat more exciting.)

Does some function or algorithm $f($*player, board*$)$ exist that gives me a number measuring how connected the *player's* sides of the board are given the *board* configuration? (Would tend to -Infinity for a loss, $0$ for an empty board, and $+\infty$ for a win)

I've actually tried modelling it as a diffusion problem numerically, but computation time becomes an issue there, and situations like this lead to problems with that approach too:

```
0 0 0 X 0 0 0
0 0 0 X 0 0 0
0 0 0 X 0 0 0
Y Y Y X Y Y Y
0 0 0 X 0 0 0
0 0 0 X 0 0 0 
0 0 0 X 0 0 0
```

I'm just a dumb physicist, so this area of math is totally outside my area of expertise!!!

Comment: Well the game can be viewed as a tree, so you can think of the measure as the probability of reaching a winning leaf in the tree.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_tree

Comment: There are lots of different sorts of functions that might be relevant, depending on what properties you'd like it to satisfy. For example, the number of pieces that must be placed for each player to win might be useful, but if a player has more winning options you might want to weight your function based on that. Or maybe something more detailed about exactly how "far ahead" a player is in this simplified version would be appropriate. Unfortunately, Hex and related games like this are PSPACE complete, so you can't really make the board bigger and get exact data.